# Summation of recursive formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, recursion, mathematical-modeling, geometric-series

In modelling a certain problem I find the following sum that I am trying to find a formula for $f_1+f_2+f_3...+f_n$ where
\begin{align}
&f_1=t_1+(a+y(t_1-t_0))k\\
&f_2=t_1+\Bigg(a+2y(t_1-t_0)+\bigg(\Big(a+y(t_1-t_0)\Big)k-ak\bigg)y\Bigg)k\\
&f_3=t_1+\Bigg(a+3y(t_1-t_0)+\bigg(\Big(a+y(t_1-t_0)\Big)k-ak\bigg)y \\
&+ \bigg(\bigg(a+2y(t_1-t_0)+\Big(\big(a+y(t_1-t_0)\big)k-ak\Big)y\bigg)k-ak\bigg)y\Bigg)k\\
&.\\
&.\\
&.\\
\end{align}
Notice that the equation of $f_3$ takes up two lines. I found that $f_n$ is given by the recursive formula
\begin{align}
f_n=t_1+k\bigg( a+ny(t_1-t_0)+y\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (f_i-t_1-ak) \bigg),\;\;\;\;\; f_1= t_1+k(a+y(t_1-t_0))
\end{align}
I know it is very messy and probably very hard to find a formula for the sum or even a non-recursive formula for $f_n$. The pattern is that you add $t_1$ and then some factor multiplied by $k$. Now this factor gets messy and very large quickly. This factor is given by $a+ny(t_1-t_0)$ and then adding each preceding factor minus $ak$ multiplied by $y$. I know its quite a nasty summation, but I will try my luck here!

Comment: So the number of terms in the formula increases as $n$ increases?

Comment: All the terms will always have the form $t_1+Xk$, the number of terms that the factor X consists of will increase. I see that the formating was a bit poor because of the long equation, I will try to fix that!

Comment: No, I think the formatting is fine.  I just wanted to be sure I understood.

Answer (score 3):

We can simplify your formula quite a bit, but it doesn't result in a recurrence that I know how to solve.  We have $$\begin{align}
f_n&=t_1+k\left( a+ny(t_1-t_0)+y\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (f_i-t_1-ak) \right)\\
&=t_1+ka+kny(t_1-t_0)+ky\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}f_i-ky(n-1)(t_1+ak)\\
&=t_1+ka+n(ky)(t_1-t_0)-n(ky)(t_1+ak)+ky(t_1+ak)+ky\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}f_i\\
&=\alpha+n\beta+ky\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}f_i
\end{align}$$
where $$\begin{align}
\alpha&=t_1+ak+ky(t_1+ak)\\
\beta &=-ky(t_0+ak)
\end{align}$$

if I haven't made any mistakes.

This is easier to compute with and think about, but I don't see any way to get an explicit formula for $f_n$.  I had hoped we might end up with a recursive formula for $\sum f_i$, but the coefficient of $ky$ seems to exculde any possibility of that.

This really should be a comment, not an answer, but I have no hope of typing it in a comment box.

Comment: In the third row counting from where the equations begin, you have a $-ky(t_1+ak)$, shouldn't it be $+ky(t_1+ak)$

Comment: @alibakly Yes, I think you're right.  I'll change it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from Saulspatz answer:
$$
f_n = \alpha+n\beta+ky\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}f_i
\\\Leftrightarrow\\
\sum_{i=1}^{n}f_i=\frac{f_n -\alpha-n\beta+ky f_n }{ky}
$$

Also, with $n\leftarrow n+1$:

$$
f_{n+1} = \alpha+(n+1)\beta+ky\sum_{i=1}^{n}f_i
\\\Leftrightarrow\\
\frac{f_{n+1}  -\alpha-(n+1)\beta }{ky}= \sum_{i=1}^{n}f_i
$$

Substituting one equation into the other, we obtain
$$
f_{n+1} = f_n·(k·y + 1) + β
$$

This is a inhomogenous linear recurrence with constant coefficients, so you can compute the explicit form of $f_n$, and using that, probably the explicit form of $\sum f_n$.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm not really familiar with recurrence problems so how would I go about trying to find an explicit formula for $f_n$?

Comment: You can try to repeatedly substitute the definition of the recurrence into the right side and look if you can see a pattern.Alternatively, look at $e_n := f_{n+1}-f_n$, which loses the inhomogenous part, and try to guess the explicit formula of $e_n$. Then use $f_{n+1} = f_0 + \sum_{i=0}^n e_n$

Comment: Let $\phi=(ky+1)$ and $f_1=\gamma$. I get \begin{align}&f_1=\gamma \\ &f_2=\gamma\phi-\beta \\ & f_3=\gamma\phi^2-\beta\phi-\beta \\ &f_4=\gamma\phi^3-\beta\phi^2-\beta\phi-\beta \end{align}. I do see the patern. It looks like a powerseries.\begin{align} f_n=\gamma \phi^{n-1} -\beta \phi^{n-2}-...-\beta\phi^2-\beta\phi-\beta.\end{align} But is there no other way to express this more explicit and how would I go about finding the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{m} f_n$?

Comment: I now see that \begin{align} f_n=\gamma \phi^{n-1} -\beta( \phi^{n-2}+...\phi^2+\phi+1),\end{align} which with a geometric sum gives \begin{align} f_n=\gamma \phi^{n-1} -\beta \frac{1-\phi^{n-1}}{1-\phi}\end{align}

Comment: Just a small remark: in your last equation you have:$$
f_{n+1} = f_n·(k·y + 1) - β.
$$ Shouldn't it be $$
f_{n+1} = f_n·(k·y + 1) + β \;?
$$

Comment: This is what I was trying to do yesterday.  I can't believe I couldn't make it work.

Comment: @alibakly Thanks for pointing it out! I'll go ahead and correct it